# How to set a dropdown as a required field in C# Razor if a checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

In the ASP.NET Core 3.1 webapp I have a check box, "Food", which is of a boolean type and should be bind to a property HasFood, and I'd like to know how to manage this:

If the check box is checked:

A dropdown list Caterer becomes a required field.
A request cannot be submitted unless the Caterer option is selected from the list.
If the check box is not checked:

The Caterer dropdown list is not a required field.

I am total new to razor, I even dont know how to implement a checkbox. so if you could give me the whole code for this problem, I would be **very very** thankful

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the check box is checked: A dropdown list Caterer becomes a required field

> If the check box is not checked: The Caterer dropdown list is not a required field.

To achieve the requirement, you can try to implement [remote validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#additional-fields), like below.

```
//...

public bool HasFood { get; set; }

[Remote(action: "RequiredOrNot", controller: "Home", AdditionalFields = nameof(HasFood))]
public string SelectedCaterer { get; set; }

//other properties
//...
```

*Action method*

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult RequiredOrNot(string selectedCaterer, bool hasFood)
{
    if (hasFood && selectedCaterer == "0")
    {
        return Json("The SelectedCaterer field is required.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

*View page*

```
<form asp-action="CreateCaterer">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="HasFood" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HasFood)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SelectedCaterer" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="SelectedCaterer" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Caterers">
            <option value="0">---Select---</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SelectedCaterer" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Test Result

[image]

***Update:***

Above example would works well within ASP.NET Core MVC application. If your project is an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, you can achieve same remote validation using `PageRemote` attribute, like below.

```
public bool HasFood { get; set; }

[PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "The SelectedCaterer field is required.",
    AdditionalFields = "HasFood,__RequestVerificationToken",
    HttpMethod = "post",
    PageHandler = "RequiredOrNot")]
public string SelectedCaterer { get; set; }
```

*The handler method*

```
public JsonResult OnPostRequiredOrNot(string selectedCaterer, bool hasFood)
{
    if (hasFood && selectedCaterer == "0")
    {
        return new JsonResult(false);
    }

    return new JsonResult(true);
}
```

You can check the following doc to know more about implementing Remote Validation in Razor Pages:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation/remote-validation

Comment: Visual studio doesnt find Json. What nuget package do I need to install here?

Comment: <form asp-action="CreateCaterer"> here is an error: cannot resolve action CreateCaterer. Can you help?

Comment: Hi @Peter, it seems that your app is ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, not MVC app. You can check my new update to implement Remote Validation in Razor Pages.